# How to find all specific dict objects with static value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

I have many dicts in my dictionary sturcture like

```
x = {'Shoes': 'http://www./', 'sub_categories': []}
```

It appears in some lists in dictionary

is there some possibility to remove all such objects like 'x' from my dictionary?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit with a more complex example? All lists? Some lists? Which lists? What do you mean with "all such objects"?

Comment: Are you saying that `x` is one value inside a larger dict? Show us this dict.

Comment: So are you saying you want to remove all key-value pairs that have the key of `x`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dict` comprehension to iterate over the items, and check if the value is a `list` using `isinstance`.

```
>>> d = {'Shoes': 'http://www./', 'sub_categories': []}
>>> {k:v for k,v in d.items() if not isinstance(v, list)}
{'Shoes': 'http://www./'}
```